# Como mandar emails na versão de php 4.3.11?

Tags: php, email, envio-de-email

Como consigo enviar emails na versão de php 4.3.11? Tenho um site hospedado num servidor onde a versão do php é essa e a função `mail()` não funciona. Existe maneira de contornar o problema?

Comment: Explique não funciona. Dá algum erro? Você simplesmente não recebe o e-mail?

Comment: entre em contato com o suporte e peça a atualização do PHP, seria o melhor a fazer.

Comment: Upgrade meu amigo. PHP 4.3.11 não se usa mais. Já pede pra instalar o 7.

Comment: Simplesmente não manda email, não recebo nada. Penso não ser possível pedir a atualização de servidor

Answer (score -1):

Normalmente os "hostings" permite a mudança do "engine" do php através do Painel de controle. Entre em contato com eles. Deve haver algum wiki deles que possa te ajudar.